# How to make string in Python

Tags: python, string

Hello guys thank you for see my question :)
I'm trying to make **KaprekarsConstant** but it's not running because Hnum, Lnum is not int.
So i want to make it to int, but i don't know how to do it
Please help me
Thank you for your reading.

```
def KaprekarsConstant(num):
    count = 1
    while num != 6174:
        Hnum = "".join(sorted(num))
        Lnum = "".join(sorted(num, reverse=True))
        num = Lnum - Hnum
        count += 1
    return count
```

Answer (score 2):

To sort the number in ascending/descending order, you have to first cast it to a string, and then change the result back to an int for your computations, as follows:

```
Hnum = int("".join(sorted(str(num))))
Lnum = int("".join(sorted(str(num), reverse=True)))
```

This should allow your algorithm to run.

Comment: I really appreciate your help.  I just tried to use int at first,  but it was not work.  String is the anwser. Thank you again.